# c# replace "\n" text with newline in a textbox

Tags: c#, replace, textbox, newline

I have some text (for example "o\nour first place, and this\n\n13") and I want that for each "\n" string founded into the text this must be replaced with newline...

output for the example will be:

o
our first place, and this

13
How can I make? textbox is multiline

the code is

```
string text_str = txtbox.Text;
text_str .Replace("(?<!\r)\n", "\r\n");
txtbox.Clear();
txtbox.Text = text_str;
```

Comment: So if a literal backslash n (`"\\n"`) is typed in the box, you want it to replace it with an actual new line (`"\n"`)?

Comment: Your example doesn't match what are you saying. the letter _o_ should be on its own line, _our first place...._ on another line, then a blank line and finally the number. Please fix the example or explain better what are you trying to achieve

Comment: I think there may be some confusion about whether the idea is to allow a _user_ to be able to type in a literal \n vs. replacing a \n in a string with a \r\n (i.e., Environment.Newline) when it is not already preceded by a \r. Presumably in most applications, we would not expect users to type \n. The latter, however, makes sense because on Windows, a TextBox ignores a \n without a preceding \r and the text gets run together. Looking at the above attempted implementation, I'm guessing that what you are really after is a Regex.Replace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
string text_str = txtbox.Text;
text_str = text_str.Replace("\\n", "\r\n");
txtbox.Clear();
txtbox.Text = text_str;
```

Although that's a really round about way of doing things. This will accomplish the same thing:

```
txtbox.Text = txtbox.Text.Replace("\\n", "\r\n");
```

Comment: thank you, this work but why it's necessary "\\n" insted "\n"?

Comment: Can you explain how this can possibly work? Strings are immutable. The Replace doesn't change the text_str in any way

Comment: @Steve Good catch. I didn't look at his code too carefully.

Comment: @pcluddite I suggest you to test this code, also with the change the replace doesn't seem to work at all, the double backslash is wrong for me

Comment: @Steve This code works fine for me. How are you testing it?

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
txtbox.Text = txtbox.Text.Replace("\\n", Environment.NewLine);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

```
string text_str = "o\nour first place, and this\n\n13";
text_str = text_str.Replace("\n", "\r\n");
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

Note very sure what the OP needed, but in case someone else comes here looking for what I was:

```
blah.Text = Regex.Replace(origString, "(?<!\\r)\\n", "\\r\\n")
```

Comment: Or use Environment.NewLine in place of "\\r\\n" to make it more platform-independent.

Comment: Agree, change to Environment.NewLine but this is the best answer - most of the other answers don't handle scenarios where the string contains a mix of \r\n and \n.